# Is the flamingo project still alive?

Tags: java, user-interface, ribbon

I want to use a ribbon menu in java and found the [flamingo project](http://java.net/projects/flamingo). Unfortunately the most links to the flamingo project page are dead and it seams as there isn't a lot movement going on.
Does anyone know if the project is still alive and developing?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was reanimated in December 2016, there were Maintenance Updates since February 2017 and [now Flamingo is part of Project Radiance](https://www.pushing-pixels.org/2018/05/23/hello-radiance.html).

[image: Radiance]

Answer (score 2):

Flamingo has been moved. The project is still being actively updated. You can get the source, documentation and jar file for flamingo here [Insubstance 6.3](http://www.shemnon.com/speling/)

Comment: the tutorial is over there as well...? i wonder why they dont put it on github / java.dev with its explanation (step by step). @Flexo

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like the project's being updated, but the source is available:
https://github.com/kirillcool/flamingo