# Java Swing Ribbon Menu

Tags: java, swing, ribbon

How would you go about implementing a ribbon menu in Java, without the use of any third party software or code?

Thanks

Comment: Step 1: start coding, Step 2: finish coding Step 3: smile. Notice, there is no step "ask bad questions".

Comment: Why not using third party code?

Comment: It's part of an assignment where it has to be written yourself, and I thought flamingo was a third party software but it seems to just be a library! Thanks ppeterka!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Flamingo JRibbonComponent](http://java.dzone.com/articles/flamingo-tutorial)

## 2022

Because the internet never stands still - [Flamingo Github Repo](https://github.com/kirill-grouchnikov/flamingo) - but you could have probably Googled that

And also, just to point it out, the original link was to the tutorial, not the source

Comment: Flamingo is not there anymore.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194155/is-the-flamingo-project-still-alive

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The original link links to the tutorial page, which is, mostly, still there.  You could also google "java flamingo" to find the git hub repo, which will link you to the Radiance repo, none of which is, IMHO, terribly difficult.  I mean this post was made nearly 10 years ago, to be honest, I'm surprised that anybody can still find ANY of it 

Comment: I did not expect a “anyone can google” comment from a 334k rep user when just pointing out stale links.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Not intended as an insult, but I've run into simular dead links before from answers and just used it as a starting point for a google search, which is what I did to get the updated repo link, I was just saying 

Answer (score 0):

I would use Swing to create a tabbed pane, with each tab containing a series of buttons or other Swing components.

Then get to work on the look & feel of the tabbed pane to tweak it to what you're after.   E.g. http://zzhelev.blogspot.com.au/2007/07/creating-custom-ui-delegate-for.html